# OpenVPN only redirect traffic that uses the openvpn network interface

Tags: openvpn

I have a standard OpenVPN client setup on Windows 10 with this config (Windscribe VPN):

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote nl.windscribe.com 443

nobind
auth-user-pass

resolv-retry infinite

auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 2
mute-replay-warnings
remote-cert-tls server
persist-key
persist-tun

key-direction 1
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
```

The OpenVPN client (v11.13.0.0) creates a new network interface called `Ethernet 3` (TAP-Windows Adapter V9).

I have a client where I can specify the network interface it has to use, this is set to the `Ethernet 3` adapter, this works, all traffic gets redirected through the VPN.

The issue is that ALL other traffic also gets redirect through this adapter.

I tried adding `redirect-gateway` to the config but then the traffic through `Ethernet 3` doesn't work anymore, it doesn't seem to be connected to anything.

Is this possible with OpenVPN?

Answer (score 1):

Some OpenVPN servers push routing configuration to clients. While this is a good practice in general, in some situations you may want to control which traffic goes through VPN. Let assume, that tunnel network is a.b.c.d/24, then:

```
route-nopull 
route a.b.c.0 255.255.255.0
```